# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC + views: exception when switching from AddDefaultIdentity to AddIdentity

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have opened a test project (.NET 6, VS2022) based on ASP.NET Core MVC and views template (not Razor pages), with activated individual user accounts.

`Program.cs` looks like this (from the template):

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options ...

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();
```

So far so good.

Now I added some example code to seed the user database, which needs access to the `RoleManager`:

```
var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();`
```

However, that throws an exception

> No service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'

which could be fixed (thanks Stackoverflow) by changing the `AddDefaultIdentity()` to `AddIdentity()` which introduces `IdentityRole`:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options ...
```

However, now I get an exception further down with

```
app.MapRazorPages();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'

Which services need to be configured and how?

When I remove `app.MapRazorPages();`, the user management pages (login, user registration) do no longer work (404 error).

When I instead add `builder.Service.AddRazorPages()` above, the routing is also broken: a route to `"/account/login"` is missing, probably because Razor pages are somewhat differently organized than MVC controllers. Obviously, I do not want Razor pages, just Razor logic in a few views, and basically MVC architecture.

I am, honestly, a bit confused, since the official documentation does not help much.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue in my side, but I failed to find an official document which guide me to access to the RoleManager. Then I tried to searching for the error message, and I found this configuration `services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`. Could you pls let me know which tutorial you followed to access to the RoleManager ?

Comment: Hi, I have seen this in a life REST project (uses `builder.Services.AddControllers();` (thus, without the views). The tutorial is by Nate Barbettini, page 90: [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/recaffeinate-files/LittleAspNetCoreBook.pdf) which is about .NET5, but the command (and the life project) should work with .NET6 as well.

Adding your recommendation now throws at `var app = builder.Build();` (I did: `builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

Comment: I shared all I did in my side and no issue. could you pls take a look at what I post below and compare it with yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow your document, I fount that what you did is adding an initialization to create data in the database. So I created a new .net 6 MVC app and integrate [default authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-web-app-with-authentication). Pick up Authentication type field with `Individual User Accounts` when creating the project, then run `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console window. Now I have a empty .net 6 MVC project with default asp.net core authentication.

Next, I followed the document and created a `SeedData.cs` file in the root folder:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebAppDefIdentity
{
    public static class SeedData
    {
        //public const string AdministratorRole = "Administrator";

        public static async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider services) {
            var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            await EnsureRolesAsync(roleManager);
        }

        private static async Task EnsureRolesAsync(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            var alreadyExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator");
        }

    }
}
```

And the document is .net 5 oriented project, so need a little change. In the `Program.cs` file, adding following codes.

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var aa = scope.ServiceProvider;
    await SeedData.InitializeAsync(aa);
}
```

[image]

Then I reproduce your first exception

[image]

To solve this exception, I changed in `Program.cs` with code `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()`

[image]

Then no exception.
[image]

Comment: Basically, adding the scope and initializing SeedData seems to be similar as done in the tutorial, only I had put that at the end, just before `app.Run()`. So probably the solution here is to put it directly after `app = builder.Build()` and *before* the critical `app.MapRazorPages` which caused by second exception. Now it works for me, too. Good job and thank you for the effort!

Comment: many thanks for informing me and I'm glad to see your code worked well : )